# authorization rails_admin with pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, pundit

I use pundit gem to authorization.

In my file `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :pundit

  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
  ......
end
```

I follow the instructions in `https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit`
But in when run code, error :

```
protected method `policy' called for #<Rails_Admin::MainController
```

I use rails_admin 0.8.1

Please guide me use pundit in rails_admin ( tutorial, examle, ...)

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40390333/3840858

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [this](https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit) gem or just make default authorization.

Add this to `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` file:

```
  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.root_path, error: 'You are not authorized to perform this action.' unless current_user.admin?
  end
```