# Rails_admin and pundit: undefined method `policy' for #<RailsAdmin::MainController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, pundit

[image]
I'm on rails 5 and I'm trying to implement authorizations with pundit for my rails_admin panel. So I included pundit in my application controller and installed [the rails_admin_pundit gem](https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit/) as you can see in this snippet of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.0'
gem 'rails_admin-i18n'
gem 'rails_admin_tag_list', github: 'kryzhovnik/rails_admin_tag_list'
gem 'pundit'
gem "rails_admin_pundit", :github => "sudosu/rails_admin_pundit"
```

The application policy:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :current_user, :record

  def initialize(current_user, record)
    @user = current_user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

    def rails_admin?(action)
        case action
        when :dashboard
            @user.admin?
        when :index
            @user.admin?
        when :show
            @user.admin?
        when :new
            @user.admin?
        when :edit
            @user.admin?
        when :destroy
            @user.admin?
        when :export
            @user.admin?
        when :history
            @user.admin?
        when :show_in_app
            @user.admin?
        else
            raise ::Pundit::NotDefinedError, "unable to find policy #{action} for #{record}."
        end
    end

end
```

And a snippet of my rails_admin initializer:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :pundit
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
  ...
end
```

So now when I load the admin dashboard (url: "/admin") I get this error:

> undefined method `policy' for #RailsAdmin::MainController:0x0055914e2523a0>

I followed all the instructions, but I still don't see what's missing. Any answer/suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This bugged me too. Eventually found: https://travis-ci.org/sferik/rails_admin/jobs/152180750

rails_admin now defaults to `::ActionController::Base`

To fix, put the following in rails_admin.rb:

`config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationController'`

Comment: nice answer. Works for me