# Setting up rails_admin with Pundit 2 - do I need the rails_admin_pundit gem? How to do without?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, pundit

I'm introducing [the RailsAdmin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) in my app. I already use Pundit 2 for authorization. I'd like to use Pundit to deal with authorization – for now, simply give every admin the access to RailsAdmin, and keep other users out. In the future, it may be more complex than that.

I've seen there is a Gem called [rails_admin_pundit](https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit). However, what confuses me is that the [RailsAdmin Wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki) says about this gem:

> (this gem is for users of Pundit 1.x - the Pundit 2.x API has built-in support in RailsAdmin)

But I can't find anywhere how to use Pundit in Rails Admin.

I've uncommented the line `config.authorize_with :pundit` in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` but after that no clue on what to do without the rails_admin_pundit gem.

If I just do nothing, I get:

```
undefined method `policy' for #<RailsAdmin::MainController:0x0000561fdeaa60a0>
```

Raising in the file `rails_admin (2.0.0) lib/rails_admin/extensions/pundit/authorization_adapter.rb:62:in`policy' `, at this line:

```
        def policy(record)
          @controller.send(:policy, record)
        rescue ::Pundit::NotDefinedError
          ::ApplicationPolicy.new(@controller.send(:pundit_user), record)
        end
```

I can find solutions here and there, but they suppose using the rails_admin_pundit gem.

I'm quite tempted to do like said here [authorization rails_admin with pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288801/authorization-rails-admin-with-pundit) and just do not use Pundit and rely for now on `user.admin?` method.

Any idea on where to find documentation on using RailsAdmin and Pundit 2 together? Or how to contact the authors of the gem to know how we're supposed to do?

Comment: The wiki says `RailsAdminPundit` is for " for users of Pundit 1.x". You say you're using `Pundit 2`. The wiki says the "Pundit 2.x API has built-in support in RailsAdmin". So, `RailsAdminPundit` seems irrelevant to your current situation. Am I misreading? Also, your contemplated approach seems reasonable on face value. Any reason you're concerned with this approach?

Comment: Can you try putting `config.parent_controller = "ApplicationController"` in your `rails_admin.rb` and **restart** the server to see if it works without the gem?

Comment: @Toribio There is progress in this case! If I put the parent controller, and then I put a `dashboard?` method in the ApplicationPolicy, I can see an empty Dashboard. If I try to put a `@user.admin?` method on each CRUD action, it raises again `"undefined method export? for #<ApplicationPolicy:0x00007fa0b6ea8bd0>"` in  `lib/rails_admin/extensions/pundit/authorization_adapter.rb:39:in authorized?'`.

Comment: I think you'll need to define the rails admin policies in your default application policy file. One of them is `export?`. I'm just not entirely sure how to implement these policies in the new included pundit extension, but I think it's just like the example in the `rails_admin_pundit` [README on GitHub](https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit).